# phpMyAdmin reCaptcha error allow_url_fopen=0

Tags: nginx, php, phpmyadmin

I've got phpMyAdmin running on Nginx. I also enabled reCaptcha `$cfg['CaptchaLoginPublicKey'] = 'secretkey'` and `$cfg['CaptchaLoginPrivateKey'] = secretkey'`.

I added the above to `config.inc.php`. As you can see below, I have reCaptcha enabled. The secretkeys are entered correctly also. But when I login I get the following errors:

> Entered captcha is wrong, try again!
>
> Warning in
>   ./libraries/plugins/auth/recaptcha/ReCaptcha/RequestMethod/Post.php#68
>   file_get_contents(): https:// wrapper is disabled in the server
>   configuration by allow_url_fopen=0

I'm sure I entered the corret captcha.

According to this [Bug Report](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=784628) the issue was going to be solved in the next release. I'm using the latest *phpMyAdmin version 4.6.2* with PHP7.0.

In my php.ini, `allow_url_fopen = off`.

Any body knows are workaround for this one?

Thank you.

**UPDATE:**
Problem is fixed if **allow_url_fopen = On**. But is there a solution to the error stated above since I want to set this to **OFF** for security reasons.

[image]